# Formula to sum up the rational below 1 with bounded demoninator?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a formula that describes the sum of rationals with a maximum denominator such as 5 that are smaller than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(N)$ be the sum for denominators $\le N$.
Then $$F(N) = \sum_{n=2}^N \sum_{\{i \; :\; 1 \le i \le n-1, \text{gcd}(i,n)=1\}} \dfrac{i}{n} $$
For a given $n$, there are $\varphi(n)$ terms (where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)).  Since $i$ is included if and only if $n-i$ is, 
the inner sum is $\phi(n)/2$.  Thus 
$$F(N) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=2}^N \varphi(n)$$
See OEIS sequences [A015614](http://oeis.org/A015614) and [A002088](http://oeis.org/A002088).

Comment: If you want to include $1$, just add $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $5$ is the maximum denominator the rational numbers less than $1$ are $$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4},
\frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}$$

They are easy to sum up by hand.

If you specifically want a formula then use the formula for sum of an arithmetic progression for each denominator from $n$ from $1$ to $n-1$ subtract those that are reducible since they have already been added, divide by the denominator and then add those.

Comment: Yes, but i world not like to sum up repeated values, I'm wondering about the fastest way to do this computationally?

Comment: Well saying $\underset{(p,q)=1}{\sum}$ is fine for a formula. If you're looking for how to program your computer to do it try adding an 

if(nominator is not divisible by any of the simple factors in the denominator){add the fraction to the sum}